# iOS Simulator doesn't show full app

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator

I've been working on an app in Xcode; however when running the application in the iOS Simulator for iPhone 5s, it doesn't show the full app and sliding doesn't help, screenshots below.

[how it looks in xCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raM0V.png)
[how it looks in iOS Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo0cr.png)

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: disable size classes in file inspector and try

Comment: Or better, leave class sizes enabled and set the appropriate constraints to describe where the elements should be placed

Comment: I'm guessing you need to tell the simulator to show you a 50% view.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot of the iOS Simulator window shows scrollbars.  I suspect you can scroll up to see the buttons on top or just adjust the scale (in the Window menu) to fit everything into a window without scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Just press `command 2` it will make you simulator shrink.